# What is the best way for me to perform a delete using EF 6 and a repository?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am looking at these two examples from two different repositories:

```
    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
            DbSet.Remove(entity);
        }
    }

   public virtual void Delete(T entity) {
        dbset.Remove(entity);
   }
```

Can someone explain the difference. Why did the author of the first add all the additional lines?

Comment: In linq-to-SQL you "Delete" things, in EF you "Remove" things.  They accomplish the same task.  My guess is that the Delete method was created as a wrapper so that they didn't have to update as much existing code when switching from linq-to-SQL to EF.

Comment: I have doubts about the first one... If the entity already exists on the context in the `Added` state, it will be changed to `Deleted` when it should be `Detached` instead. And if an entity is already in the `Deleted` state, I'm not sure why it would need to be reattached and marked as `Deleted` again.

Comment: Don't fall for the trap of over-complicating things, EF *is* your repository, wrapping it in another layer reduces the readability and features of your code. Sure, add some helpers here and there, but use it and all the power it gives you properly, don't put kiddy-gloves on your calling code. Oh and the 2nd one is the right way, the wrapping of the `dbset.Remove(entity);`. Helps show how pointless that is for a repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way for me to perform a delete using EF 6 and a repository?

I can't answer your question. Here's why.

If you want to delete an object through Entity Framework two things must be true:

- The object must be attached to the context.
- The object must be in a `Deleted` state.

The aim of the **first** `Delete` method seems to be to ensure that both conditions will be met after it has run. But that's not as simple as it seems. It has to sniff out the object's current state, attach it if necessary, set its state if necessary. And, not even accounted for yet, it also has to make sure it's not attached to any other context. This, and Anthony Chu's comments show that the first method isn't nearly complex enough yet.

So keep it simple and use the **second** method? Well, the second method presumes that the calling code knows it's alright to just call `dbset.Remove`, it knows all the things the first method tries to find out. But if it's that smart already, why would it be too dumb too call `DbSet.Remove` directly? (Aside from the fact that the second method itself is pretty dumb, as Timothy Walters points out).

And then, there are three ways to mark an object as `Deleted`:

- `Remove` it from a `DbSet`
- Mark the state of the `DbEntityEntry` as `Deleted`
- (Under certain conditions) `Remove` it from a parent's child collection

Trying to confine all deletes to calling one repository method may be a great restriction to writing the best code.

That's why I can't answer your question. I don't believe in repository layers on top of `DbSet` anyway. So as for me, the best way to perform deletes depends on what the code of each of your use cases looks like.